# How to express a 2nd order ODE as 1st order ODE's?

Tags: differential-equations, education

Is there a built-in function that expresses a 2nd order ODE as 1st order ODE's?
If not, how can one decouple a 2nd ODE to a first-order one using Mathematica?

I couldn't find it here: [Why is NDSolve solving in term of two 1st order ODE slower than 2nd order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13072/why-is-ndsolve-solving-in-term-of-two-1st-order-ode-slower-than-2nd-order)

Comment: Yes: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132668/reduce-ode-into-1st-order/132764#132764

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks!

Comment: Also see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html#504426794

Answer (score 0):

Using `NonlinearStateSpaceModel`

```
fode = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[m y''[t] + c y'[t] + k y[t] == f[t], {y[t], y'[t]}, f[t], {}, t]
```

> [image]

To extract the parts

```
With[{res = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[fode, {x1[t], x2[t]}] // Normal},
 ApplySides[MatrixForm@*Transpose@*List, D[res[[2]], t] == res[[1, 1]]]]
```

> [image]

Comment: the `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` is really neat, thanks!
But this raises the question: How come I couldn't find it in the documentation while searching for a built-in function that converts an ODE to a first-order system?